# Computing the norm of an operator, references or examples

Tags: reference-request, examples-counterexamples, intuition

I am struggling a lot when I try to compute the norm of an operator. I was wondering if someone here could recommend a book/chapter/online notes/ other resource that I can look into to get a better feeling of the techniques and general ideas we use to compute the norm of an operator.

I know the definition of an operator norm is $\|T\| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1}\|Tx\| = \sup_{x \neq 0} \frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}$ but that doesn't really help me when I actually  need to compute this kind of stuff. Thanks for any help or resources.

Comment: This is kind of like showing that a function is continuous: apart from telling you to apply the definition, there is little we can do to help you in general. Do you have a concrete example that you have been working on where you are stuck?

Comment: I read about operator norm in the convex optimization book by Boyd. I think of T as an operator and in that sense the operator norm is measuring the maximum change the operator provides.